The best way to reduce the calculation time of formulas in nested loops?
Could you tell me what is the best way to reduce the calculation time of formulas in nested loops? I have code like this:
for k in range(0, 130):
    for i in range(0, 1600):
        array2[i,k] = 0
        for j in range(0, 1600):
            array2[i,k] = array2[i,k] + constant_value * (array1[j,k] * function1(i - j))

Array1 and array2 contain double numbers. This block of code executes in 15-20 minutes. The problem is that the block is nested in another loop that has 100 to 400 iterations, so sometimes it takes more than 24 hours to calculate. Is there a way to speed up this piece of code?

There are only 2 * 1600 - 1 unique values of i - j, but you calculate function1(i - j) 1600 * 1600 * 130  times.

The value array1[j,k] * function1(i - j) is recalculated for every combination of i and j, but this value only depends on i and j, so it might be possible to optimize by storing the result in a temporary array.

Use the functools.cache decorator to optimize repeated calls of function1() with the same argument.

Instead of recalculating function1(i - j) for each i and j, you can create a 2D array function_values of size 1600×1600, where each element corresponds to function1(i - j). This will allow to perform operation once instead of repeatedly in the loop.

Thank you for your suggestions.function1 has two if's inside and depending which if is triggered the different formula is calculated and returned. @Yuri Ginsburg Your're right and it's even more complex cause i have one more loop outside the fragment of code. So it's 100-400 * 1600 * 1600 * 130. As @Nikhil Sawant suggested it may be good to store values in tmp array and reduce calculations thanks to that.

As others have pointed out, the values passed to function1 in the inner loop are duplicated many times so if it is an expensive function that is wasteful.
Instead you can build a toeplitz matrix from only the unique function return values:
import scipy

ni = array1.shape[0]
function_values = function1(np.arange(1 - ni, ni))
function_values = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(
    function_values[ni-1:], 
    function_values[ni-1::-1]
)

Combining this with my other answer to this question gives:
array2 = constant_value * np.dot(function_values, array1)

Explanation
A toeplitz matrix is a matrix in which each descending diagonal from left to right is constant.  So if you give it the values of i and -j for the left column and top row it will produce a matrix that matches the values of i - j at each iteration.
print(scipy.linalg.toeplitz([0, 1, 2], [0, -1, -2]))
# [[ 0 -1 -2]
#  [ 1  0 -1]
#  [ 2  1  0]]

jj, ii = np.meshgrid([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
print(ii - jj)
# [[ 0 -1 -2]
#  [ 1  0 -1]
#  [ 2  1  0]]


I think the best way would be to parallelize the following part of your code with Jax (it can help you even if function1 is not a pure function)
constant_value * (array1[j,k] * function1(i - j))

Pseudo code if it is a pure function:
> Pre-calculate each value for all i and j combinations
> use Jax for parallel multiplication of the above part of the code 
> generate the value of array2[i,k] in the similar way with these precomputed values

If it is not a pure function then you can refer the following link to see how to you can parallelize it.
Refer this link

Numpy is designed to vectorize calculations in Python.  To figure out how to vectorize a calculation in nested loops like this, you are best to break it down step by step.
Since you didn't provide them, I'm going to use the following for testing my method:
array1 = np.arange(12).astype(float).reshape((3, 4))

def function1(x):
    return 100.0 - x

constant_value = 2

first let's deal with that function1 in the inner two loops:
test = np.full((3, 3), np.nan)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        test[i, j] = function1(i - j)

print(test)
# [[100. 101. 102.]
#  [ 99. 100. 101.]
#  [ 98.  99. 100.]]

You can vectorize this with a 2D meshgrid:
jj, ii = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(3))
print(function1(ii - jj))
# [[100. 101. 102.]
#  [ 99. 100. 101.]
#  [ 98.  99. 100.]]

The array1[j, k] contains k which is the iterator of the outer loop.
So for a given k, we can do this:
array1[:, k] * function1(ii - jj)

Let's check that:
k = 0

# Original code
array2 = np.zeros_like(array1)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        array2[i, k] = array2[i, k] + (
            constant_value 
            * array1[j, k] 
            * function1(i - j)
        )
print(array2)
# [[2440.    0.    0.    0.]
#  [2416.    0.    0.    0.]
#  [2392.    0.    0.    0.]]

# Vectorized
print(
    np.sum(
        constant_value 
            * array1[:, k] 
            * function1(ii - jj),
        axis=1
    )
)
# [2440. 2416. 2392.]

To vectorize the outer loop we need to use an additional dimension:
print(np.expand_dims(array1.T, 0).shape)
# (1, 4, 3)

Complete solution:
jj, ii = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(3))
array2 = constant_value * np.sum( 
    np.expand_dims(array1.T, 1) * function1(ii - jj), 
    axis=2
).T
print(array2)
# [[2440. 3046. 3652. 4258.]
#  [2416. 3016. 3616. 4216.]
#  [2392. 2986. 3580. 4174.]]

Check it matches the original code:
# Original code
array2 = np.zeros_like(array1)
for k in range(4):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            array2[i, k] = array2[i, k] + (
                constant_value 
                * array1[j, k] 
                * function1(i - j)
            )
print(array2)
# [[2440. 3046. 3652. 4258.]
#  [2416. 3016. 3616. 4216.]
#  [2392. 2986. 3580. 4174.]]

Update
Based on the comment from the question author below, here is an alternative solution that avoids unnecessary evaluation of function1 and also avoids building the mesh grid in memory (which might be large) by iterating over the indices instead.  This should be more memory efficient but might be slower due to the for loop.
# Evaluate and store function for unique values only
ni = array1.shape[0]
function_values = function1(np.arange(1 - ni, ni))

def get_function1_value(i, j):
    return function_values[i - j + ni - 1]

array2 = np.zeros_like(array1)
for i, j in np.ndindex((ni, ni)):
    array2[i] = array2[i] + constant_value * array1[j] * get_function1_value(i, j)

print(array2)
# [[2440. 3046. 3652. 4258.]
#  [2416. 3016. 3616. 4216.]
#  [2392. 2986. 3580. 4174.]]

Update 2
I just noticed that you can use a dot product here:
jj, ii = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ni), np.arange(ni))
array2 = constant_value * np.dot(get_function1_value(ii, jj), array1)


Tip: To avoid leaving ii and jj in memory (they could be large) you should delete them or you could do this instead: function1(np.subtract(*reversed(np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(3)))))

@ Bill Great explanation. It is really helpful. Thanks. Would it be the same if indexes of an array are, let's say from -500 to 500 so array1 can be like array1[-500, -500], array1[-500, -499], ..., array1[500,500]. So function1 can be then like that function1(-500 - (-500)) or function1(500 - (-500)). In that case I should just change np.meshgrid function. Am i right?

Not sure I completely understand but you can’t directly index an array with negative indices.  What you could do is make a lookup table of all the unique values of i - j and only pass those to function1.  That’s similar to what I am doing in the other answer using function1(np.arange(1 - ni, ni)).

I added an alternative solution based on my comment above.  Let me know if that's what you were thinking or not.
